# Content of /proc/<PID>/cmdline file depends on script shebang?

Tags: shell-script, process, arguments, shebang

I have a `bash` script named `test.sh` which I start with `startproc`. In case I use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang in `test.sh`, the `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` file looks following:

```
SERVER:~ # cat /proc/29481/cmdline
bash/root/user/test.shSERVER:~ # 
SERVER:~ #
```

Now when I change the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash`, the `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` file is following:

```
SERVER:~ # cat /proc/29729/cmdline
/bin/bash/root/user/test.shSERVER:~ # 
SERVER:~ #
```

What causes such behavior? Does the content of `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` file depend on script shebang? The problem is that in case of former option `checkproc`, `killproc` or `startproc` are not able to detect the `test.sh` service. I use openSUSE 11.4 with `sysvinit-tools-2.88-37.47.1.x86_64`.

Comment: Just guesses, but in the first case the kernel calls bash and fills in `cmdline`, whereas in the second case it does the same with `env`, but the bash `cmdline` you are looking at is set by `env`.

Comment: In the first case, the kernel sees `#!` and logically executes `/bin/bash /root/user/test.sh`. In the second case, `env` sees `bash` and logically executes `bash /root/user/test.sh`. These both refer to the same binary. The contents of `/proc/cmdline` should basically be equivalent to the process's `argv`, IIRC, and `argv[0]` has always been dependent on the invocation, regardless of which binary is actually executing.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the `cmdline` will vary depending on exactly what `exec*` system call was made, and a fully qualified path may be different than what `env(1)` turns up from its path search.

```
bash-4.1$ cat aaa
#!/bin/bash
xxd /proc/$$/cmdline
bash-4.1$ cat bbb
#!/usr/bin/env bash
xxd /proc/$$/cmdline
bash-4.1$ ./aaa
0000000: 2f62 696e 2f62 6173 6800 2e2f 6161 6100  /bin/bash../aaa.
bash-4.1$ ./bbb
0000000: 6261 7368 002e 2f62 6262 00              bash../bbb.
bash-4.1$
```

`strace` shows the particulars:

```
bash-4.1$ strace ./aaa 2>&1 | grep exec
execve("./aaa", ["./aaa"], [/* 57 vars */]) = 0
bash-4.1$ strace ./bbb 2>&1 | grep exec
execve("./bbb", ["./bbb"], [/* 57 vars */]) = 0
execve("/sbin/bash", ["bash", "./bbb"], [/* 57 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/sbin/bash", ["bash", "./bbb"], [/* 57 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/local/sbin/bash", ["bash", "./bbb"], [/* 57 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "./bbb"], [/* 57 vars */]) = 0
bash-4.1$
```

If this is a linux-only script, then the location of `bash` will likely not vary (exception: there's a software depot of some sort that includes `bash`, elsewhere). Therefore, using the fully qualified path probably makes the most sense, as this avoids `env(1)` flailing around in a path search, and gains compatibility with the init tools.

Answer (score 1):

The command line of a process consists of the elements of the `argv` parameter of the [`execve`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) system call. This parameter is an array numbered from 0, where elements number 1 through n are the arguments passed when invoking the command, and element 0 is chosen by the shell or other program that issues the `execve` call. Conventionally, element 0 is the string used to designate the command.

Shebang lines are processed by the kernel. The kernel inserts an argument 0 which is the path specified after the `#!` magic prefix. So if you run `/root/user/test.sh` with the one argument `foo` from `startproc`, then `startproc` makes an `execve` call with two arguments 0=`/root/user/test.sh`, 1=`foo`. When `/root/user/test.sh` starts with `/bin/bash`, the kernel sees the shebang in `/root/user/test.sh` and rewrites the argument list to 0=`/bin/bash`, 1=`/root/user/test.sh`, 2=`foo`.

If the shebang line is `#!/bin/env bash`, then the kernel inserts two items in the argument list: the program and the argument. (Linux is limited to a single argument here.) So in this case the invocation is transformed into 0=`/bin/env`, 1=`bash`, 2=`/root/user/test.sh`, 3=`foo`. The `env` program does its job and issues a new `execve` system call with 0=`bash` (respecting the convention that argument 0 is the path used to designate the command), 1=`/root/user/test.sh`, 2=`foo`.

In all cases, `/root/user/test.sh` will be the first argument of the process.